# Javascript enabled but not enabled in Firefox browser

Tags: 12.04, firefox, java

I  had installed  Java

```
ii  icedtea-6-jre-cacao                           6b24-1.11.5-0ubuntu1~12.04.1                    Alternative JVM for OpenJDK, using Cacao
ii  icedtea-6-jre-jamvm                           6b24-1.11.5-0ubuntu1~12.04.1                    Alternative JVM for OpenJDK, using JamVM
ii  openjdk-6-jre-headless                        6b24-1.11.5-0ubuntu1~12.04.1                    OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT (headless)
ii  openjdk-6-jre-lib                             6b24-1.11.5-0ubuntu1~12.04.1                    OpenJDK Java runtime (architecture
```

and had installed addon in Firefox browser QuickJava 1.8.0.

And still keep getting message `Javascript enabled, but Java is not enabled in Firefox browser` while trying to use on-line bill payment facility.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't have the required browser plugin installed.

The following commands will install version 7 instead of version 6 because it is more secure. If version 6 is required, just substitute the command accordingly.

**First,**

open a terminal and typing the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install icedtea-plugin icedtea-7-plugin
```

**After installation**,

restart firefox, click on "Add-ons", select "Plugins", and set the plugin to "Always Activate" (I believe you must enable the plugin here first, so that it may be available to the "quickjava" extension).

---

Also, [webupd8.org](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html) maintains security updates for an Oracle Java installer ppa. The newest version is version 8 but versions 6 and 7 are also available. This package includes the non-opensource Oracle version of Java JDK, JRE, and the browser plugin as well. Type the following commands in an open terminal to install this package:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

You may change the last command from version 8 to install version 6 or 7 accordingly.

See here for more info: [install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html)

Also, for security purposes, it best use "quickjava" to disable the java plugin when it is not in use.

Comment: On a side note: this is an NPAPI plugin so it won't work with google-chrome, chromium, and certain versions of opera. However, **this plugin should be fully supported by firefox.**

Answer (score 0):

Open firefox ,Type `about:config` in address bar.
Click  on I'll be careful,I promise

Find  `javascript.enabled` option. . Change it to `true`.